# Safari opens iframe in new tab

Tags: html, iframe, safari

I am trying to open a link in an iFrame. The following code works in both Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. Safari opens the link in a new tab. 
I have also tried setting an id on the iframe (id = name), but that did not help.

```
 <iframe name="videoframe" src="" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" 
 webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

 <a href="{{$skill->url}}" target="videoframe">{{ $skill->title }}</a>
```

The $skill->url holds a valid url, and the $skill->title holds a title.

I need some help as to how to get safari to open this link in the iframe, and not in a new tab.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I had a similar issue. After some time I've found out, that the problem was caused by opening the page from the Safari's feature called 'reading list' (it's something like a bookmark feature, but for undead sites).